# typeorm: what is the difference between getRepository() and getConnection()?

Tags: typescript, typeorm

https://typeorm.io/#/select-query-builder/how-to-create-and-use-a-querybuilder

There are several ways how you can create a Query Builder:

Using connection:

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

const user = await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .select("user")
    .from(User, "user")
    .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .getOne();
```

Using entity manager:

```
import {getManager} from "typeorm";

const user = await getManager()
    .createQueryBuilder(User, "user")
    .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .getOne();
```

Using repository:

```
import {getRepository} from "typeorm";

const user = await getRepository(User)
    .createQueryBuilder("user")
    .where("user.id = :id", { id: 1 })
    .getOne();
```

The documentation never explains the difference among these methods.
When to use each method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source code:

[`getConnection()`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/globals.ts#L132):

```
/**
 * Gets connection from the connection manager.
 * If connection name wasn't specified, then "default" connection will be retrieved.
 *
 * @deprecated
 */
export function getConnection(connectionName: string = "default"): DataSource {
    return getConnectionManager().get(connectionName)
}
```

[`getRepository()`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/globals.ts#L178)

```
/**
 * Gets repository for the given entity class.
 *
 * @deprecated
 */
export function getRepository<Entity extends ObjectLiteral>(
    entityClass: EntityTarget<Entity>,
    connectionName: string = "default",
): Repository<Entity> {
    return getConnectionManager()
        .get(connectionName)
        .getRepository<Entity>(entityClass)
}
```

[`getManager()`](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/globals.ts#LL142C65-L142C78)

```
/**
 * Gets entity manager from the connection.
 * If connection name wasn't specified, then "default" connection will be retrieved.
 *
 * @deprecated
 */
export function getManager(connectionName: string = "default"): EntityManager {
    return getConnectionManager().get(connectionName).manager
}
```

`getConnection()` returns a `DataSource`, `getRepository()` returns a `Repository` and `getManager()` returns an `EntityManager`. All of them have the `createQueryBuilder()` method,  see [Repository.ts#L77](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/repository/Repository.ts#L77), [DataSource.ts#L555](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/data-source/DataSource.ts#L555) and [EntityManager.ts#L194](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/0.3.16/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L194)

So the differences between them are:

- [What is EntityManager](https://typeorm.io/working-with-entity-manager)
- [What is Repository](https://typeorm.io/working-with-repository)
- [What is DataSource](https://typeorm.io/data-source#what-is-datasource)

Answer (score 1):

There are no meaningful differences between creating a query builder by connection, manager, or repository.

According to [one of the typeorm lead devs](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1671):

> they all are same, just aliases for the same functionality. Use what is convenient for you.